# Nodejs REST API to rewrite url or work as middleware for accessing distant photos

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express, url-rewriting

I am making a rest api with node/express for exposing data with assests urls from another servers , like this :

```
 Client ------> RestAPI with nodeJs/express (API Y) --------> API for Images (API X)
```

- The API for Images (API X): provide json or links for images with url like "http://APIX.com/link1/X.jpg"
- The assets / images are located in (API X) server .

What am trying to do is when the client calls the (API Y) and want to get data with image urls like "http://APIY.com/api/X.jpg" ,the (API Y) fetch the images from (API X) and return it to client with links from (API Y), so the client will not know the correct source of images and think that the images are hosted in (API Y) server.

Any idea on how can i implement this in NODE js/express ? thx.

Comment: If the path of the URL can be preserved, then just look up "proxy" on NPM and you can make part of your APIY.COM work like a proxy so the client talks to APIY and APIY gets images from APIX and streams them back to the client.  If you're creating all new API Y URLs that have nothing in common with the API X URLs, then it's a lot more work as you have to create a database on APIY that maps an APIY URL to the appropriate APIX resource so you can then get the right resource from APIX and stream it back to the client.

Comment: what do you mean by "url can be preserved" ? ......the idea is that the client comunicate with APIY and all assets look like the are in APIY...... im planning to create on APIY an endpoint for this assests .. this endpoint change the url or rewrite it or replace it so it can be an APIX link ..so i can avoid the database solution ......can i use the endpoint as proxy ? thanx

Comment: If you're using your own APIY URL paths that have nothing to do with the APIX paths, then you have to create a database with a mapping from APIY => APIX.  If you're exposing only your own APIY URLs, then you have to have some way to receive an APIY url and know what APIX url to go get the resource with.  Unless it's a small amount of URLs that you can keep in a config file and read into memory, you're going to need a database for that.  I honestly don't understand what question you're asking here.

Comment: FYI, rewriting the URL is the wrong term here.  Your server receives the APIY url.  It has to then go fetch the APIX url with a new request and then return that data as the response to the APIY url.  You could do a 302 redirect and tell the browser to go get the real data from APIX directly, but I was under the impression that you didn't want to expose APIX at all.  In any case, you have to be able to map an APIY url to an APIX url somehow.

Comment: @jfriend00 , yes i dont want to expose APIX at all ... i m trying to avoid extra code and handling the database mapping ...i can make it with a little bit tricky way....for example when calling the "ABC17005.jpg" from APIY ... i would make a funciton for changing the name inside the "onProxyReq" methode from "http-proxy-middlware" ..so it became "17005.jpg" which is the real name of the image on APIX ......this solution looks enough for me and dynamic ......thankx again for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jfriend00  , i manage to find a solution with your "proxy" suggestion, i used the http-proxy-middlware npm package , like follow :

- I am using express and http-proxy-middleware with Typescript

```
import express from "express";
import proxy from "http-proxy-middleware";

export default class APIYServer {
    constructor(private port: number) {}

    public start(): void {

        const app = express();

        app.use(
            //the Url exposed with APIY
            "/APIY/assets",
            proxy({
                //the Url of the APIX server
                target: "https://www.APIX.com/",
                changeOrigin: true,
                pathRewrite: {
                //"/APIX-assets-path/" is the path where images are located
                    "^/APIY/assets": "/APIX-assets-path/"
                },
                onProxyRes
            })
        );

        //function for handling proxy response
        function onProxyRes(proxyResponse: any, request: any, response: any) {
            if (proxyResponse.statusCode != 200) {
                console.log("---FAIL ---");
            }

            // DELLETING COOKIES INFOS so the client can't find source of images
            Object.keys(proxyResponse.headers).forEach(function(key) {
                delete proxyResponse.headers[key];
            });
            delete proxyResponse.headers['Set-Cookie'];
        }

        //run APIY server on port 8888
        app.listen(this.port, () => {
            console.log("Server Started on 8888");
        });
    }
}
```

- When calling "localhost:8888/APIY/assets/01.png" its give me the images located in "https://www.APIX.com/APIX-assets-path/01.png"...and that's what i m looking for :D